# How to check if column value is null before inserting data from text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am trying to insert data from text box to sql database, but I want to check if the row is empty then insert new value else update the row with the values with sqlcommands in if else condition.

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class CM : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    //DataTable dt;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server =consulting76\\SQLEXPRESS; database = msdb; Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        //("Select * from NOTESMAKER", con);
        //da.Fill(ds, "NOTESMAKER");
        //dt = ds.Tables["NOTESMAKER"];
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        if (DBNull.Value != null)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into NOTESMAKER(NOTESMAKER) Values(@text1)",con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@text1", SqlDbType.NText)).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            da.InsertCommand = cmd;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Update NOTESMAKER set NOTESMAKER = @text1)",con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@text1", SqlDbType.NText)).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            da.UpdateCommand = cmd;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Not like this. First you need to fetch data from database. Then check whether it is empty or not

Comment: which row your talking about?a textbox or in you database

Comment: @Anand - I'm talking about row in Database

Comment: ok,but you didn't check for null value,i mean you didn't use 'select 'query

Comment: @Anand - How do I do that ? I'm sorry I'm new to C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't know how to fired a select query, have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)

select * from tablename where columnName is not null

fill sqldataadapter from your query [eg](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter)

if dataset count is zero then you may proceed with insert operation else update.

```
if (ds.table[0].rows.count==0)//insert
        {

        }
        else// update
        }
```

Comment: I am doing this:  
    `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from NOTESMAKER where NOTESMAKER <> NULL", con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        //dt = ds.Tables["NOTESMAKER"];
    }`

Comment: How do I check the Dataset count is zero or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way. `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of affected rows, so if insert returns 0, it means that there was nothing to update. Hence you need to insert a row.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Update NOTESMAKER set NOTESMAKER = @text1)",con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@text1", SqlDbType.NText)).Value = TextBox1.Text;
int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (affectedRows == 0)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into NOTESMAKER(NOTESMAKER) Values(@text1)",con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@text1", SqlDbType.NText)).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```